# Using $http in angular jhipster entities

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster, angular-http

What is the proper way to update some entity field from Angular view/controller.

Let's imagine we have a"to-do" app in which we want to change "Task" entity status from 1 to 0 from a ng-click event and store that change in the database.

How can we create that functionality in our controller so we can call it when checking/unchecking a checkbox?

Lets set the playground:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasklist.tasks">

    <checkbox ng-change="completeTask({{taskId:task.id}})"></checkbox>
    <span>{{task.title}}</span>  

</div>
```

In Controller we want to change "task.status" from 1 to 0 or viceversa when checkbox click:

```
    //If we need to obtain that task object from api
    var task = Task.get({id : $stateParams.taskId}).$promise;

    //Now how should the function work?

        $scope.completeTask = function () {




        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster exposes a REST API so to update an existing task either you use `PUT /api/tasks/123` with the full entity or you define a sub resource and you implement and use `POST /api/tasks/123/complete` which should return a 303 HTTP status code.

Do some research about PUT/POST and partial updates in REST.

Then in angular part, with first approach, generated `task.service.js` has everything you need with `update` function, second approach requires more work.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this would simply be an event when the checkbox is clicked. Here's an example, straight from the [docs](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/eventhandlers/changeevents/). This is pretty straight forward stuff if I'm not missing something, potentially complete a good tutorial or two on Angular before you dive into building stuff!

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="mainModule">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <h3>2. Change event on checkbox</h3>
    Select a checkbox<br />
    <label>Check1: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check1Selected" ng-change="onCheckBoxChange()" /></label><br />
    <label>Check2: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check2Selected" ng-change="onCheckBoxChange()" /></label><br />
    <strong>RESULT:</strong> {{onCheckBoxChangeResult}}<br />
    <br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module("mainModule", [])
  .controller("mainController", function ($scope)
  {
    // Initialization
    $scope.onCheckBoxChangeResult = "";

    $scope.onCheckBoxChange = function () {
      $scope.onCheckBoxChangeResult = "Check1 is " + ($scope.check1Selected ? "SELECTED" : "NOT SELECTED") +
        ", " + "Check2 is " + ($scope.check2Selected ? "SELECTED" : "NOT SELECTED");
    };
});
```

Now modify that to your use case, as it functionally has all the requirements to make your code work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Sorry Nick, maybe was my fault not to be clear enough, I know this is basic stuff, the problem I have is how should I work when i need to update some particular attribute from an entity taken via Api from the database, so it fits the coding standards Jhipster (angular+spring yeoman generator) has followed.
Thanks a lot again.

Comment: What database are you using, and do you know the name of the API for database querying? I'm not familiar with JHipster, but from what I just read you can choose a database, and I'm not sure of where to find the API docs for JHipster database queries.